# Remove rows from tensor by matching

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I'm trying to do some operation like if there is tensor in pytorch

```
a = torch.tensor([[1,0]
                  ,[0,1]
                  ,[2,0]
                  ,[3,2]])


b = torch.tensor([[0,1]
                  ,[2,0]])
```

I want to remove the rows [0,1], [2,0] which are the rows of `b` from `a`.

Is there any way to do this?

```
# result
a = torch.tensor([[1,0]
                  ,[3,2]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do it if the tensor shapes were broadcastable.

For a tensor `a` of shape `(?, d)` and a tensor `b` of shape `(d,)`, you could write something like:

`cmp = a.eq(b).all(dim=1).logical_not()`, i.e. compare each `d`-dimensional row of `a` with `b` and give me the indices where the comparison is `False`.

From these you can then easily your new tensor like so:
`a = a[cmp]`

I doubt you'll find an elegant way of doing this when `b` itself contains a batch dimension; your best bet would be to write a for loop.

Full example:

```
>>> xs = torch.tensor([[1,0], [0,1], [2,0], [3,2]])
>>> ys = torch.tensor([[0,1],[2,0]])
>>> for y in ys:
...     xs = xs[xs.eq(y).all(dim=1).logical_not()]
>>> xs
tensor([[1, 0],
        [3, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this exploiting broadcasting:

```py
import torch
a = torch.tensor([[1, 0], [0, 1], [2, 0], [3, 2]])
b = torch.tensor([[0, 1], [2, 0]])

indices = ((a == b[:, None]).sum(axis = 2) != a.shape[1]).all(axis = 0)
print(indices)
print(a[indices])
```

indices =

```
tensor([ True, False, False,  True])
```

a[indices] =

```
tensor([[1, 0],
        [3, 2]])
```

Works for all tensors `a` and `b` of shapes *m x n* and *p x n* respectively i.e, the number of columns (`a.shape[1]`) must be same and you can compare among any no. of rows.